# How to push content div to footer div while keeping background in the picture

Tags: html, css, background, footer, absolute

I have been having this problem for weeks now searching through different websites with no solution to my problem. I looked through this website, stackoverflow, and the answers were not exactly what I was looking for. I ended up using Forty Seven Media's [Making Your Footer Stay Put With CSS](http://fortysevenmedia.com/blog/archives/making_your_footer_stay_put_with_css/) and it worked pretty well. The problem is with screen sizes and the height of the div. If the page is long, it looks really nice. When the content div is short of content in comparison to the screen size, however, the page has whitespace in between the content and the footer. When you zoom in or out of the page you'll see the problem.

How can I get the content div to extend to the footer keeping my background in the whole div?

I made dummy code to simulate my website. The images can be substituted by anything so you can see what I'm talking about. The background will have to be quite large. Index and Another Page are the two dummy pages with differing content.

The HTML is below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Dummy page</title>
  <link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container" class="neo-sans-text">
    <div id="header" class="container-center">
      <a href="../home.html"><img class="hcenter" src="../images/dummy-logo.gif" alt="Waves" /></a>
    </div><!-- end header-->

    <div id="background-container" style=background-image:url("../images/background/Big_wave.jpg")>
      <div id="nav">
        <ul>

          <div class="link-box">
            <li><a href="anotherPage.html">Another Page</a></li>
          </div>

          <div class="link-box">
            <li><a href="index.html">Index</a></li>
          </div>

          <div class="link-box">
            <li><a href="../contactUs.html">Contact Us</a></li>
          </div>

        </ul> 
      </div> <!-- end nav -->

      <div id="content-container">
        <p class="uppercase big-font">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin gravida sed nulla eget eleifend.</p>
      </div> <!-- end content-container -->

      <div id="clearfooter"></div>

      <div id="content-footer">
        © Copyright 2014 Big Waves, LLC
      </div>
    </div> <!-- end background container -->
  </div> <!-- end container -->
</body>
</html>
```

The CSS is below.

```
/* CSS Document */
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}

#container{
    min-height:100%;
    position:relative;
    margin-bottom:-50px;
}

#header{
    padding:1%;
}

#header img{
    height: 80px;
    width: 170px;
}

#background-container{
    background-size:cover;
    background-color:#097;
    padding-left:100px;
    padding-right:100px;
    padding-bottom:20%;
}

#nav li{
    list-style: none;
}

.link-box{
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
}

.link-box a{
    text-decoration: none;
    border: 12px #000;
    padding:5px;
    background: rgba(149, 185, 199, 0.4);
}

#content-container{
    padding-left:230px;
    padding-right:230px;
    clear:both;
}

#content-container table{
    width:200px;
}

#content-container img{
    width:35px;
    height:35px;
}

#clearfooter{
    height:30px;
    clear:both;
}

#content-footer{
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    background-color:#099
}

.container-center{
    text-align: center;
}

.element-center{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
}

.uppercase{
    text-transform:uppercase;
}

.big-font{
    font-size:28px;
}
```

I would prefer an answer using only CSS for convenience, but other answers are surely welcome. Any suggestions are welcome. Thank you in advance!

**Edit**: There are multiple pages with differing content sizes and backgrounds for reference.

Comment: Consider setting your background image as the background of the body, rather than the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either add the background to the body (btw, try adding styles only to CSS, don't use inline styles) or if you can't, use something like this:

```
body{100vh}
header{height:10vh}
#content{height:80vh}
footer{height:10vh}
```

This way you will have full screen with no white spaces (assuming this is what you're looking for) and you can add the bg to your content div with no blank space

Comment: Thank you so much! This is a great solution and it removes the whitespace. There are only a couple problems. If we zoom in, the text will disappear. If we increase the content, the page breaks. You'll see what I mean if you copy paste a couple Lorem Ipsoms. 

The inline styles are there because the background is different and the text has different styling :(

Comment: this is because you have to set the viewport meta in your document's head, like `<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">`

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about the viewport meta tag, so I did some research and now I'm back. It zoomed out very well, but it didn't zoom in the best. I read that the     maximum-scale would set the zoom level, yet when I tested it, it still zooms in breaking the page when we don't want that.

Answer (score 0):

```
background-attachment:fixed;
```

This will keep the background-image in your screen.

Answer (score 0):

A workaround for this may be to set the entire page to have the background you want for your footer, and then individually set the backgrounds for all elements above the footer.  Just make your footer have `background-color: transparent`.

**Edit:** as proposed by TylerH.

Answer (score 0):

To get around this, I made the entire body the colour that you wanted and changed the header colour to white. This seemed to work.

```
body {
    background-color:#097;
}   
#header {
    padding:1%;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Here is a link to the full file if you need it:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ofhawycygn2p1tu/Page.html?dl=0